# Django -- printing lots of documents?

Tags: django, printing

I have a Django app that stores client data. Currently, there are just over 1,000 clients in the database. Twice a year, I need to print a semi-customized letter for each client. Ideally, I want to be able to click a button/link and the entire batch is sent to the printer; I don't want to have to click "print" for each letter since that would be absurdly time consuming.

I have thought of is using [Celery](http://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to chug through the process of printing all the documents, but I don't know how that would be accomplished. I would have to 'build' the document and send it to the printer without the user seeing this happen.

The other idea I had was to create a "web page" that contains all the letters on one page. Then the user can hit "Print" and the pages would come out of the printer as a collection of letters. Although, this seems sloppy.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise using wkhtmltopdf for this task. You can then create the required letters from one long html with pagebreaks or separately and print them as you regularly print PDF's.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

As wk stands for WebKit it will print exceptionally good quality PDF's. It's a commandline tool that you can just download and run. Small tutorial is here for you.

http://shivul.posterous.com/django-create-dynamic-pdfs-using-wkhtmltopdf

ReportLab is also a good option. But myself I don't want to create raw pdf syntax and Pisa the html library for ReportLab is not really that good. wkhtmltopdf is much better and easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply/link. Although that wkhtmltopdf looks like a good option, your second paragraph hinted at an even easier solution that I might just explore -- even though I claim it's "sloppy". Instead of converting HTML to PDF, why not just create a huge HTML page from a view, and insert **pagebreaks** (as you stated) between each letter? I hadn't even thought about a `pagebreak` within the HTML code, rather assumed I would have to mess around with getting a DIV to be the precise height of an A4 piece of paper.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using something like Reportlab to create the whole thing as a single PDF document that you can send to the printer in one go.

See the docs on [generating PDFs from Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/outputting-pdf/).